# Removing object from Arraylist on basis of sorting

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a list having  4 objects and each object has 4 attributes. I want to remove the object having the greatest 4th attribute.

Here is what I have done.

```
double temp = 0.0; 
List<type> list1=new ArrayList<>(); //this list has 4 objects

List<Double> attribute1List = new ArrayList<>(); //list of attribute1
for(int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
      attribute1List.add(Double.parseDouble(list1.get(i).getattribute1()));
}

for (int i = 0; i < attribute1List.size(); i++) {
      if (attribute1List.get(i) > temp){
           temp = attribute1List.get(i); //temp is the greatest
       }
}
```

Since temp gives me the greatest. So, now how do I get the index of the greatest in list1 so that I can remove the particular object from list1.

Comment: what is `distances` ?

Comment: oh,replace it with attribute1List.

for (int i = 0; i < attribute1List.size(); i++) {
      if (attribute1List.get(i) > temp){
           temp = attribute1List.get(i); //temp is the greatest
       }
}

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify this by doing

```
double temp = 0.0; 
List<type>list1=new ArrayList<>();//this list has 4 objects

type biggest = null;    
for (type t : list1)
      if((Double.parseDouble(t.getattribute1()) > temp){
           biggest = t; 
           temp = t.getattribute1();
       }
}

// then remove biggest - should check not null
list1.remove (biggest);
```

Comment: yes, this is an optimized solution, no need of creating a separate list for holding attribute1

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thankyou!

Comment: @Vaibhav Please consider to upvote and/or accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
double temp = 0.0; 
int greatestIndex;
List<type>list1=new ArrayList<>();//this list has 4 objects

for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
      if((Double.parseDouble(list1.get(i).getattribute1()) > temp){
      temp = list1.get(i);
      greatestIndex = i;
     }
}
list1.remove(greatestIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a variable as index. like below, then remove that item from the list:

```
double temp = 0.0; 
List<type>list1=new ArrayList<>();//this list has 4 objects

List<Double> attribute1List=new ArrayList<>();//list of attribute1
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
      attribute1List.add(Double.parseDouble(list1.get(i).getattribute1()));
}

int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < attribute1List.size(); i++) {
      if (attribute1List.get(i) > temp){
           temp = attribute1List.get(i); //temp is the greatest
           index = i;
       }
}
list1.remove(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you should use `TreeMap` for this. Using `treemap`, your object with greatest value will be stored at last (since **treeMap** stores value in *sorted order*) and then you can remove last value from your `treeMap`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8, it should be something like this:

```
Type element = list1.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Type::getAttribute1())).get();
```

Then remove it

```
list1.remove(element);
```

Comment: I omit the parsing double stuff for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

```
 list = list.stream()
                .sorted((Comparator.comparingDouble(Type::getattribute4).reversed()))  // sorting DESC by atr4
                .skip(1)                           // skip first bigger
                .collect(Collectors.toList());     // collect into new list and replace old on =
```